# Python function does not return the second value

Tags: python

I want the function to return two types of value, string and integer when counting vowels in a word. Upon invoking I'm getting only the y value, but not the x. Can you explain why is this happening?

```
def cnt_vow(s):
    x = 0
    y = ''
    for char in s:
        if char in 'aeuio':
            y = y + char
            x = x + 1

    return y 
    return x

cnt_vow('hello')
```

expected: `'eo', 2`

was: `'eo'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both, try returning a tuple

```
return x,y
```

`return` always leaves the current function, so code after it will never be executed.

Comment: yes, it works that way. So the return command just returns the value from the loop without even noticing the second return statement?

Comment: @minerals: Correct. Read `return x` as 'return x to where I was called, and leave this place now!'

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use a tuple to return multiple values:

```
return (y, x)
```

where the parenthesis are usually optional.

When calling this function, you can then unpack the two values again:

```
vowels, count = cnt_vow('hello')
```

Once python sees a return statement the function execution ends, a second statement is never reached.

Answer (score 1):

Once your code hits the first return statement, it returns the specified value immediately.

What you're looking for is:

```
 return y, x
```